# Fill in operators (7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 = 820)

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

My kid's git the following as his homework - the problem is to fill in arithmetic operators between eight digits 7 to get 820, that is:

7_7_7_7_7_7_7_7=820

This drives me mad, but I myself cannot find the answer!

Comment: It can't be done if you're allowed only the symbols $+, \times, -, /$, and respecting the usual conventions of operator precedence.

Comment: @PatrickStevens You don't usually give importance to the mathematical order of operations in these sums.

Comment: Can we put brackets if we like?

Comment: It can't be done using sequential operations either, ignoring the usual precedence, although I'm in a rush and slightly less sure of my program here.

Comment: Brackets are allowed.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it cannot be done and there is a typo, but just wanted to be sure...

Comment: BTW, how could you all realize so quickly that it can't be done (barring the answer below)?

Comment: @Demiurg I wrote a program to test all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$777+(7\cdot7)-7+(7/7)=...$

Comment: Hmm...this could be the answer, even though the question was formulated in such a way that I thought I must use operators between every digit

Comment: Subsidiary question: what is the age of your kid ?

Comment: ???Don't have any.

Comment: @Demiurg an exhaustive search of all possible combination of operators: times, divide, add, subtract and no operator (effectively $x\times10+y$) shows this is the only solution besides rearranging the order of the additions/subtraction..